# How to format groupby year function pandas - returns unicode attribute error

Tags: python, pandas

Using the code below in attempt to count number of entries by year, returns a unicode value error. Is there an alternative to the implementation below?

```
raw_news_4.groupby(raw_news_4["date_publish"].map(lambda x: x.year))

#raw_news_4 sample

date_publish    title
213059  2006-10-18 12:47:13 Is God dead Atheism finds a market in     US
20559   2006-11-12 13:11:20 WITNESS Waking up paralyzed in Sri     Lankas war zone
111765  2007-01-18 23:02:00 AIDS in Americas
123806  2007-01-18 23:02:00 Malaria
7060    2007-01-18 23:02:00 AIDS pandemic
121746  2007-01-18 23:02:00 Indonesia mudflow
206142  2007-01-18 23:02:00 Pakistan violence
241749  2007-01-18 23:02:00 

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Comment: What is the dtype of column `date_publish`?

Comment: `raw_news_4['date_publish'].dtype 
    # returns dtype('O')`

Comment: Convert the column to [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert date_publish to datetime dtype using `pd.to_datetime` then use `dt` accessor with `year` attribute:

```
df['date_publish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_publish'])
df.groupby(df['date_publish'].dt.year).size()
```

Output:

```
date_publish
2006    2
2007    6
dtype: int64
```